# Move documents from one subfolder to another/root folder

Tags: document-library, csom, caml

I have a document library with sub folders. I would like to move the document(s) from one folder to another/root folder. Is this possible using CSOM/CAML?

I am pretty new to Sharepoint development so pardon me if the question seems too dumb!